# Can we monitor Cassandra schema disagreement using JMX

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I know that `nodetool describecluster` can give me information about schema disagreements in cassandra . But, i am looking to see if that information is available via JMX .If it is available can some one point me fully-qualified package/metric name for this ?

I am trying setup alert for this using Prometheus .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can monitor it with JMX:

```
ObjectName: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageProxy
Attribute:  SchemaVersions
```

This will return a key/value pair, with a format similar to:

```
eaceacea-eac7-eac6-eaca-eac75275b=[172.1.xx.xx, 172.1.xx.xx, 172.1.xx.xx]
```

All the nodes in the same cluster should match the UUID returned.